# Override Email Form of lexik Mailer Bundle [Smfony2]

Tags: php, symfony, overriding

I want to override the EmailType of the lexik mailer bundle.

I tried

```
use Lexik\Bundle\MailerBundle\Form\Type\EmailType as BaseType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

/**
* @author Laurent Heurtault <l.heurtault@lexik.fr>
* @author Yoann Aparici <y.aparici@lexik.fr>
*/
class EmailType extends BaseType
{
    ...
}
```

and put it in the exact same path in my bundle MailingBundle/Form/Type/EmailType.php
But it doesn't seem to work.

May I have to make something more than that?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[You can redefine the Form Type class as parameter](https://github.com/lexik/LexikMailerBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.xml#L30), as example:

```
parameters:
    lexik_mailer.form.type.mailer_email.class: AppBundle\Form\MyEmailFormType
```

Hope this help

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either...
Putted in config.yml with correct path but no change